# How can i fix intelliSense on visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, java, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

How do i get IntelliSense and Autocomplete to function on Visual studio code

i tried doing it but the got automaticallyoverrodedefaultvalue

I don't know what that means

Comment: Can you tell me what you did? What's the problem now? If you can show some code Settings and screenshots

Answer (score 0):

restart VS Code,if not work,please use CTRL+, to open the settings page then click the right top to open settings.json and then to check wheather have any setting start with "editor" that maybe setted wrong.